# Dell inspiron 3537 keyboard and touchpad

Tags: keyboard, dell, inspiron

With new Dell inspiron 3537 the keyboard works fine with livecd. Everything stable. Touchpad doesn't work at all but this is not big deal because I have an external mouse.

But when I've installed the system on disk and I can't even pass my password. Keyboard sticks on some char and repeats (for example I try to type pete and get peteeeeeeeeeeee)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this with a boot parameter:

```
sudoedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to include `i8042.noaux` so it looks like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.noaux"
```

then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot and keyboard works.

Now only touchpad is the issue...

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Nvm. I just had to do Fn + F3.